# PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR when sorting by associated table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to sort/order a table (Employer) based on the number of associated records (Employee) each (Employer) has.

The following code works on rails console with the Employer records sorted by number of Employees as intended :

> Employer.joins(:employees).group(:id).order('count(employees.id) ASC')

However, when actually trying to run this on development, I get this error:

> PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

While I could use 'sort_by", I would prefer to have the result in ActiveRecord::Relation format. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error in the console by adding `distinct` to the expression:
In your case it would be:
`Employer.distinct.joins(:employees).group(:id).order('count(employees.id) ASC')`

The error message says that you have to add the expression you sort by (`count(employees.id)`) to the select list.
That could be achieved by explicitly specifying select columns:

```
Employer.select('employers.id, count(employees.id)').joins(:employees).group(:id).order('count(employees.id) ASC')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still returns the same error on development, but it runs on console

Comment: Could you add the code that you use "on development"?